# Adding Spacing Constraints to Text Field

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode6

I have a simple storyboard with a text field. I want to add spacing constraints to this text field so that, when I rotate the device, the text field will auto stretch across the screen instead of stopping halfway.

I have looked at multiple tutorials and they all say to "Control-drag from the text field toward the top of the scene, ending in the empty space around the text field. This should reveal a pop-up menu from which you can edit the spacing constrains of the text field."

[image]

However, when I control-drag from the text field, I get this different pop-up menu:

[image]

This other pop-menu clearly does not allow me to do anything with spacing constraints. In fact, I can't click on it at all.

Furthermore, clicking "Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues" does not work, as the entire sub-menu is grayed out.

How can I correctly add a spacing constraint to this text field so that when I rotate the device the text field will correctly fill up the screen? Please try to refrain from answers that involve editing code, as I don't actually know any Objective-C and would like to make this effect in the storyboard.

NB - If it is at all helpful, I am following [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1) tutorial. Albeit it is with Xcode 5, other tutorials on Xcode 6 suggest the same pop-up menu should exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't activate auto-layout in the first place. Check the option in the right panel, under the File section:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a new behavior of IB
For example:

Now the contents of the menu depend on the edge of where you are trying to tie constraint:

[image]

or simple use tree from left of IB

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the document outline to see the view hierarchy and try control dragging the text field to the View, it should show the options there. Your menu appears when you control drag onto the View Controller.